# Trouble with portability of Qt 5.0.2 applications. How to make minimalistic Qt package?

Tags: c++, windows, qt4

I know that Qt isn't build statically by default and if there are any files with .lib or .a extension, then these files are import libraries only. I want my applications to be small and portable, so except thinking about recompiling Qt statically I also think about how to make package of dynamic libs as small as possible that can be installed on another computer which has nothing to do with Qt, making it fully operative in case of running my Qt applications. In this case I am about Windows Xp or higher version of Windows yet. In case of creating such a package I realized at first that Qt5 installer doesn't add enything to the system and user Path and I was unable to run my compiled apps without Qt Creator. However after I added to the system and user Path variable this:

"K:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\mingw47_32\bin"

where

"K:\Qt\Qt5.0.2"

is Qt installation folder, I am able to run my apps outside of Qt Creator from any location on drive. With this fact in mind I thought that as for such a package it is enough to copy

"K:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\mingw47_32\bin"

to another computer, add it to system and user Path and everything will be as I want. Unfortunately this is not true. While being disappointed a little that I couldn't run my apps on my second PC, I'd installed the same Qt version there, made similar Path entries and everything started to work all right. More specifically, the installation directory on a second PC is:

"M:\Qt\Qt5.0.2"

and if I add to the Path this:

"M:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\mingw47_32\bin"

then it works, but if instead of it I add this:

"M:\Qt_5.0.2_libs\bin"

which contains exactly the same files as "M:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\mingw47_32\bin"

then it does not.

So my question is:

What do I'm missing so it doesn't work and how to make such a minimalistic package ?

Answer (score 0):

Deploying applications is covered in the [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html).